# Using a published paper which has some errors

Tags: publications, mathematics, errors-erratum

I have prepared a paper in which I am going to use a set of calculations ( 3 calculations) in my previously published work. In my previously published work I found that one of my calculations was wrong, however,  it did not effect the final results for that work. Currently, in a new work since I  want to use those calculations,therefore,  I want to repeat them in my current work. But I do not know how to manage it. In other words, I want to know in the case of repeating all of them, how can I explain that? Is it enough to say that

> it is a modified version

of those calculations? (with a comment on the wrong part). I know that my question seems to be a general question, but any advice to express this situation properly will be highly apprecited.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suggest that you say more. Admit to the earlier errors, correct them, show, or mention, that they don't affect the results of that paper and then proceed from there with the modified version.

But saying that it is "modified" without saying how or why is inadequate. It would give an incomplete picture.